# Selecting node in XML using XPath in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

I now have code which I think **should** work, but isn't. It returns nothing. I'm absolutely new to XML so it could just be a syntax problem.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YatU8N3.png?1]

Code:

```
Public Sub CreateXmlDom()

    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xmlNameSpaces As String

    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

    Dim strFullFilename As String
        strFullFilename = "S:\Investments\Data\Companies House\Monthly Companies House Downloads\Accounts_Monthly_Data-April2014\Prod224_0005_00011771_20131231.html"

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

        With xDoc

        If .Load(strFullFilename) Then
            .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
            .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns5=""http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core/2009-09-01"""

            Set xmlNodeList = .SelectNodes("//ns5:CashBankInHand")
        End If

        End With

End Sub
```

Element from an XML document I am trying to select:

[image]

From the doc header:

[image]

[Document full text](http://pastebin.com/1XWVyC5v)

[Document download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30073920781959898248)

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out it was a combined syntax / "didn't quite understand XML heirarchy yet" issue.

So, firstly, this isn't a Node, it's not even an attribute, it's just a value:

```
"ns5:CashBankInHand"
```

It was contained in a Node `<ix:nonFraction ...>` so the first part of my XPath string should be:

```
("//ix:nonFraction")
```

Then, `name` is an attribute so the actual query should be:

```
("//ix:nonFraction [@name = ""ns5:CashBankInHand""]")
```

Which works perfectly.